# Angular 6: Console Error: Backend returned code 200 Error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-services

I am trying to send data to database with contact form, it is sending data to database, but after, whither showing success message it is showing error message. I am also trying to login with predefined user details from database. But it is also showing error handling message in front-end and also in console message "Backend returned code 200, body was: [object Object]". How can i get solution of this.these error's showing both of case. please help...., it is **cmspage.service.ts** file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from './page';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CmspageService {

  ServerUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  errorData: {};

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(handler: HttpBackend) {
      this.http = new HttpClient(handler);
  }


  contactForm(formdata: Contact) {
    return this.http.post<Contact>(this.ServerUrl + 'api/contact', formdata, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }
}
```

Here I have set baseUrl in environment > environment.ts file, 
**contact form html**:

```
<section class="cmspage mtb-40">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-desc" [hidden]="submitted">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h1>Contact</h1>
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #contactForm="ngForm">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required #name="ngModel">
              <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                  Name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail" required email #email="ngModel">
              <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email address.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" [(ngModel)]="model.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" [(ngModel)]="model.message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required #message="ngModel"></textarea>
              <div *ngIf="message.invalid && (message.dirty || message.touched)" class="error">
                <div *ngIf="message.errors.required">Message is required.</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button [disabled]="!contactForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-success">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-error" *ngIf="error">
      <h1>{{error.errorTitle}}</h1>
      <h3>{{error.errorDesc}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!submitted" class="contact-message">
      <div *ngIf="model.id" class="contact-success">
        <h2 class="success">Success!</h2>
        <h4>Contact form has been successfully submitted.</h4>
        <br />
        <button (click)="gotoHome()" class="btn btn-info">Go to Home</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here also getting error,this is **auth.service.ts**, for login to admin dashboard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  serverUrl = environment.baseUrl;
  errorData: {};

  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  redirectUrl: string;

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.serverUrl}api/login`, {username: username, password: password})
    .pipe(map(user => {
        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getAuthorizationToken() {
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    return currentUser.token;
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }

}
```

​

Comment: In Chrome go into "network" -> reload page -> send a request you'll see it will appear and you could look at what has come back from server

Comment: It might be json not correct JSON format, could you show request response body

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you take out the `handler: HttpBackend` piece?

Comment: HttpClient will error if the server returns 200 and no body. If that is the case the server should return 204

Comment: @Jake11 which part in responsible for request response body?

Comment: @Sergey i have seen in network part, there not showing any specifically error, can you tell more descriptive?

Comment: Yes @DeborahK it not work while taking out the handler: HttpBackend piece

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi the idea of "network" is to understand whether the response from the server is okay.

Comment: What's the purpose of `HttpBackend` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

To me it feels like the backend is returning successfully. Hence you are getting a 200 status. And also for that reason, you can not see any error in network tab. Because there is no error. You are logging the status when the call to the server is successful. So the code is doing what it is supposed to do. But what i can say is that it is not getting the data as expected. The server is not returning the data as you are expecting. It might be the case of server returning an array(or list of object) but you are not expecting that on the front end. Try checking out what the server is returning. Look at the api signature or if you have the back-end code look at what it is returning.